# Recursive Function In Mathematica

Tags: function, recursion, wolfram-mathematica

Consider :

```
dist = Parallelize[
   Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {100000}]];
```

How could I create a recursive function such that :

```
Subscript[d, 1] = dist[[1]]

Subscript[d, 2] = .95 Subscript[d, 1] + dist[[2]]

Subscript[d, 3] = .95 Subscript[d, 2] + dist[[3]]
```

And do this till `Subscript[d, 100000]`

Thank You.

It is surprisingly the first time I run into this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, should the `dist[[i]]` be `0.05*dist[[i]]`?  (If not, I'm curious as to the application for this.)

Comment: @Brett,you will see more, in the "contingency table" question I asked soon after. Simulating some market volatility :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
dist = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {100000}];

dist2 = Rest@FoldList[0.95 # + #2 &, 0, dist];

Subscript[d, x_] := dist2[[x]]
```

I don't normally use Subscript this way; I don't know what may break doing this.  If you describe more of your problem, I may have an alternate suggestion.

Comment: Thank You ! The Subscript is just because I am working with my cousin and wrote as He spoke. How would you do ?

Comment: @500 I am not saying it's necessarily wrong, just that I am not comfortable with it.  I would use something like `d[x_]` or `func[d, x_]` rather than attaching a definition to `Subscript`.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, got it ! I have never dealt with this before, I will adopt your format !

Comment: +1 for using generating all 100000 values in one call, instead of using a `(Parallel)Table`.

Comment: @Brett, thank you.  Why did you change it to `RandomVariate`?  This is not in version 7.  In version 8, is it faster than `RandomReal`?

Comment: I don't think there's an significant speed difference between `RandomReal` and `RandomVariate`; the advantage of `RandomVariate` is that it can automatically select the correct type (real vs. integer vs. ...)  So it becomes easier to take the code, and change it from `NormalDistribution[...]`, to say `PoissonDistribution[...]`.

Answer (score 2):

How about using something like

```
In[1]:= dist = ParallelTable[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {100000}];//Timing

Out[1]= {0.15601, Null}

In[2]:= folded = FoldList[.95 #1 + #2 &, First@dist, Rest@dist]; // Timing

Out[2]= {0.056003, Null}
```

which you can compare to

```
In[3]:= Subscript[d, 1] = dist[[1]];
        Do[Subscript[d, n] = 0.95 Subscript[d, n - 1] + dist[[n]], 
           {n, 2, Length@dist}] // Timing

Out[3]= {1.09607, Null}

In[4]:= Table[Subscript[d, n], {n, 1, Length@dist}] === folded

Out[4]= True
```

Comment: (playing comment tag) -- I was sorry, because I first wrote "how is this different from my answer?" and then realized you acknowledged as much.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: oh - I was wondering. Yeah, I got the notification that you had posted an answer just as I was cleaning up the In/Out numbering - so I decided to post anyway. After all, the `Do` loop I give does implement something like what the OP originally had in mind. (If it wasn't early Sunday morning, then I might have been quicker and beaten you!)